# DB Schema design : single table with more columns vs multiple tables with fewer colomns

Tags: database, database-design, mysql

What would be better DB design for a social network website.
A single table with more columns and less rows or multiple table with fewer columns but more rows.

For example:
User can post an update on their wall or in a group.

Two DB designs that I could think of are:

1)
**UserPosts**: id, userId, post, datetime
**UserGroupPost**: id, groupId, userId, post, datetime

**Potentail problem :** Might require joins, which can (in future) be a slow query.

2)
**Posts**: id, userId, groupId, post, datetime 
(where groupid would be null if user posts on their wall)

**Potential Problem :** Looping over large dataset could take a (long)time.

Where can I get better performance when data increases?
Is there any other(better) way?

Comment: [First normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) and [Second normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form) may be what are you looking for.

Comment: better to ask on the [DBAs SE site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Is starting a greenfield app with a non-normalized database a case of [PrematureOptimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) ?

Comment: Every time you de-nnormalize a schema you should know that you are giving some flexibility away. Database design optimization requires complete analysis and vision including future requirements. In many cases you can buy performance but you can rarely buy flexibility without shutterning large part of the code. I suggest you begin with a 3NF first.–  Emmad Kareem 8 hours ago

Answer (score 2):

Any thing ("Entity") that can exist on its own, independently of anything else, should have its own table.

**User**: id, name, hashed_password, join_date, birth_date

**Group**: id, name

Relationships between things require generally require "linking" tables.

**Post**: id, user_id, group_id, post_date, post_title, post_content

The key to success is proper *indexing* of any field where you join between tables or on which you filter results.
Also, consider using a dummy (non-NULL) Group value for posts to a user's own "wall" - NULLs are often *not included* in indexes, which will make your queries for these posts run [far] slower.

Comment: In my opinion, the post should be independent of its scope, so the post purpose (Group vs. Wall) should be a separate table. Also the dependency between user_id and group_id could be avoided so that user could switch groups or be part of several groups at the same time.

Comment: Instead of NULLs we can have some other value (0 maybe). How can we avoid a potentially slow query?

Answer (score 2):

**Joins are not slow.** They are incredible fast if you join to a primary key or indexed column. You should **not** make design decision from the assumption that joining is a problem.

Now, there may be particular cases e.g. with very large datasets or distributed databases, where joining may be a performance problem, and there are various ways to mitigate that (indexed views, denormalization, caching), but since you don't mention that you have these specific issues, I would guess it would be premature optimization to think about.

Unless you have very specific issues, you should design your data normalized, and then use indexes etc. to avoid performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would go even further:

**User:** Id, Name, *WallId*

**Post**: Id, Content, Title, *WallId* etc...

**Wall:** WallId

**Group:** Id, Name, *WallId*...

Basically, post belongs to  a Wall. Wall can belong to  a user or  a group.